# When using for a geolocation field in lightning-record-edit-form, only two digits are displayed until selected and the increment buttons don't work?

Tags: lightning-web-components

Most important is that the increment buttons don't work but displaying only 2 digits until selected is irritating.

Example LWC component to put on the Account record page named TestEditRecordForm :

```html
<template>
  <lightning-record-edit-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name="Account">
    <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
    <lightning-input-field
      field-name="ShippingLatitude"
    ></lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field
      field-name="ShippingLongitude"
    ></lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

javascript file:

```js
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";

export default class TestEditRecordForm extends LightningElement {
@api recordId;
}
```

Comment: After working with Salesforce support, the geocode input field was made into a known issue https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003eu8QAA. Although they claim it doesn't happen with custom geolocation fields.  I saw the same problem on custom geolocation fields.